# How is $\sin (x)$ differentiable at $x=\pi /2$

Tags: calculus, limits

If we use the limit formula we have that as $x\to \pi/2$ from the left we have a positive slope and as it approaches from the right we have a negative slope.
So, the right hand limit and left hand limit are different. How is it differentiable at the point then ?
We use the same logic and say $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: One slope is positive, and the other is negative, but in the limit they're both 0. For $|x|$, one limit is 1, the other is -1.

Comment: It's not the sign that's the issue with the absolute value, it's that the left and right hand limits are different. The limits are the same for sine.

Comment: The limit values may be almost same but their angles differ right ? Like for x=π/2 approaching from the left is gives us angle close to 0 while x=π/2 approaching from the right gives us an angle close to 180 degrees

Comment: Do you have a better understanding of this concept now? If there is anything unclear or confusing still, feel free to mention it!

Comment: "The limit values may be almost same but their angles differ right? Like for x=π/2 approaching from the left is gives us angle close to 0 while x=π/2 approaching from the right gives us an angle close to 180 degrees" **NO**. The limit *is* $0$, not "close to $0$". The "derivative at $x=\pi/2$" by definition is a fixed number, not an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

To respond to your comments:

> The limit values may be almost same but their angles differ right ? Like for x=π/2 approaching from the left is gives us angle close to 0 while x=π/2 approaching from the right gives us an angle close to 180 degrees.

It's not correct that "the limit values are almost the same". The left-hand limit is exactly $0$, no more, no less. The right-hand limit is also exactly $0$, no more, no less. Since the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit are equal (*exactly* equal), the limit exists.

It's true that "the angles differ", but it also doesn't matter. The definition of a derivative doesn't involve or mention angles at all.

Answer (score 0):

From the left it approaches to $0$, and from the right it approaches to $0$ as well.

Compare this to $|x|$, from the left it approaches to $-1$, and from the right it goes to $+1$.

Do you see the difference?

Comment: The limit values may be almost same but their angles differ right ? Like for x=π/2 approaching from the left is gives us angle close to 0 while x=π/2 approaching from the right gives us an angle close to 180 degrees

Comment: @NigelGoveas '0 point something' is the value of what? the slope? Remember the slope is the tangent of the angle, and for small angles $\tan \theta \approx \theta$, so there's a smooth transition around $0$. I don't see how you conclude about the 180 value

Comment: @NigelGoveas $\tan 0^\mathrm{o}= \tan 180^\mathrm{o}$. The slopes are the same.

Comment: Well, but as crosses π/2 the slope is negative and the angle is obtuse. I know the modulus of the limits are same and the approach 0. But the angles do differ so what about that ?

Comment: Zoom in on the graph of $\sin x$ at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. It flattens out. The graph of $y = \vert x\vert$ is always V-shaped at $x = 0$ no matter how much you zoom in on it.

Comment: Can you solve the left hand and right hand limit for sin(x) at π/2 rather than just saying the limit exists at π/2 which everyone has done here

Comment: I already showed it. They’re both equal to $exactly$ $0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical question. However, you can show the limit is equivalent for both the LHS and RHS by

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}\sin'(x) = \cos\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}^+\bigg) = 0$$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\sin'(x) = \cos\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}^-\bigg) = 0$$

Let’s put this example aside for a second and look at $y = \vert x\vert$ and $y = x^2$, which are similar to your example in that the slopes seem to differ at $x > 0$ and $x < 0$. Here, the derivative doesn’t exist for $y = \vert x\vert$ since the RHS and LHS limits are not equal, but the derivative does exist for $y = x^2$, so what is the difference?

You can observe the reason visually without calculating. Check https://www.desmos.com/calculator/czqmiiuxrr (the graph of the functions). Then, try to zoom in on $x = 0$. Notice that $y = x^2$ seems to flatten out the more you zoom in. However, no matter how much you zoom in on $y = \vert x\vert$, it always retains its V-shape.

$y = \sin(x)$ behaves like $y = x^2$ in this regard. It flattens out if you zoom in on $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so the slope of the tangent at that point is $0$. You can check https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l5lv0sypss (the graph of $y = \sin(x)$) to see what I mean.

Comment: That's seems more like it. It's more a technical thing than actucal calculations. Do you know of any graphs in which the right hand and left hand limits are both the same(by the derivative formula) but the function is not differentiable at the point ?

Comment: It can be shown through calculations (first part of the answer), but it can be understood much more easily when visualized in this way. Also, if the RHS and LHS limits of a function are equal at a point by the definition of a derivative, then they approach the same slope or rate of change as $x$ tends to that value. (Hence, it is defined.)

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\lim_{x\to \frac {\pi}2} \frac{\sin x-\sin \frac {\pi}2}{x-\frac {\pi}2}
=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin \left( \frac {\pi}2+y\right)-1}{y}
=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\cos y-1}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0} \left(y\cdot\frac{\cos y-1}{y^2}\right)=0\cdot \left(-\frac12\right)=0$$

Comment: Why aren't you checking the left hand right hand limits? We should check that before we say that limit exists at that point

Comment: We can repeat exactly the same steps for the left hand and right hand limits which are indeed both equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 0 *each case*. In one case the limit is *approached through* positive values, and in the other the limit is *approached through* negative values; but in each case the *limit **itself*** is the same: zero.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are considering the signs of the numerator and denominator in:
$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{\sin(x)-\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^+} \frac{\sin(x)-\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$
In the LHS limit, both numerator and denominator are negative, while in the RHS limit, the numerator is negative and denominator is positive, which seems a contradiction to you. ("So, the right hand limit and left hand limit are different.") The thing is, as others pointed, both LHS and RHS limits are eventually equal to zero.

As an easier example, consider the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=0$. By your reasoning the function must not have a derivative, while it does have it, because:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x^2-0}{x-0}=0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x^2-0}{x-0}=0.$$